Calclation of inbreeding coefficients from pedigrees
Help! I am a complete newbie to cytoscape. I need to use the inbreeding app to compute inbreeding coefficients from pedigrees of pigs which I have as
             paternal grandsire
       sire
             paternal granddam

individual                           etc... back for 6 generations
maternal grandsire
dam
maternal grandam
Can anyone please kindly provide me with an .xlsx format (and instructions!) that  can be imported into the cytoscape inbreeding app to calculate an inbreeding coefficient for the individual as above. Happy to communicate via email.  Many thanks....  Tony Brown

Please [edit] your question (don't put the detail in the comments, add it to the question) and add more detail. We need enough detail so that someone else can understand and reproduce what you are trying to do. What are you actually plotting in Cytoscape? What are the nodes of your network? What are the edges? Can you show us a (small) example of it? What is this inbreeding app? Can you link us to it in the Cytoscape App Store?

From what I can see, you don't actually import data into the inbreeding app.  What you need to do is to import your pedigrees as a directed network.  That's fairly simple -- all you need is a table (could be csv, tsv, or excel) of edges -- the nodes are inferred.  So, in your example above, I assume (I may have the directionality wrong) the table would look something like:
paternal grandsire, sire
paternal granddam, sire
where you want the names of the grandsire and granddam since the they will also have paternal and maternal sires...
Hope this helps!
